# Eclipse Sample action set button missing while developing plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

OS: Windows 7 x64; Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Juno SR2)

I am following tutorial from a book for devlelopment of Eclispe plugins. At one point I made a mistake so I decided to delete whole project (I selected "Delete project content on disk (cannot be undone)"). So I started fresh. But then, after just few initail steps: **File -> New -> Other -> (Wizard) Plug-in Project, Next, Next, selection of Hello, World template, -> Finish** when I run project it was supposed to get button on the toolbar when **Testing -> Launch an Eclipse application** is executed.

But this time there was no buton at all (Eclipse launches new instance of Eclispe). Also, I couldn't find it in **Customize Perspective -> Choose** which tool bar item to display (it should be under **Sample Action Set**).

[image]

After few failures, including erasing "runtime-EclipseApplication" folder on disk, I **created new project, named just "Hello World", and this time it works OK**, the is buton on toolbar, and there is item "Sample Action Set" in Customize perspective, and there is even "Sample Manu" on Menu Bar. Now, even if I start HelloWorldProject it also has a button and menu item etc., i.e. it works as it should.

[image]

But, if I now delete HelloWorld, then even HelloWorldPlugin reverts back (!) and now (when test instance Runtime WorkBench is started) it again don't have button and menu bar?

**What gone wrong and how should I fix it?** I mean this is just an example, I can just go on with another project name, but in real production environmet if I have strict specification I can't get out so easily, and that is why I would like to know **what happend and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix it, but  **I still don't know why it happened** on the first place and especially **why it persisted, even after several complete deletes of project?**

The fix is: **Run -> Run Configuartions ->Plug-ins tab -> Workspace -> (select) HelloWorldPlugin**.

[image]